# output: none error your probably allocating too much memory can anyone explain in detail

Tags: java

Review below source code

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Double object = new Double("2.4");
        int a = object.intValue();
        byte b = object.byteValue();
        float d = object.floatValue();
        double c = object.doubleValue();

        System.out.println(a + b + c + d );

    }
}
```

> output: none
>   error
>   your probably allocating too much memory

can anyone explain in detail

Comment: From where did you get `error your probably allocating too much memory`? An online judge?

Comment: yes when i ran the code in a web ide

Comment: works for me `8.800000095367432`

Comment: can anyone explains how the code works in detail

Comment: what do you not understand?

Comment: how the output comes in decimals

Comment: @shalini what do you expect instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to

```
Double object = new Double("2.4");
int a = object.intValue();
byte b = object.byteValue();
float d = object.floatValue();
double c = object.doubleValue();

System.out.println(a);        
System.out.println(a + b);        
System.out.println(a + b + c);        
System.out.println(a + b + c + d );
```

and explore

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still looking for answer as why 15 decimals precision comes into picture.

```
public class JavaExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double object = new Double("2.4");
        int a = object.intValue();
        byte b = object.byteValue();
        float c = object.floatValue();
        double d = object.doubleValue();
        float e = object.floatValue();
        double f = object.doubleValue();

        System.out.println("int :"+a);        
        System.out.println("int and byte addition :"+(a + b));        
        System.out.println("int, byte and float addition :"+(a + b + d));        
        System.out.println("int, byte, float and double addition :"+(a + b + c + d));   
        System.out.println("float and double addition :"+(c + d));  
        System.out.println("float and float addition :"+(c + e)); 
        System.out.println("double and double addition :"+(d + f)); 
        System.out.println("float and double addition :"+(e + f)); 
    }
}
Output:
int :2
int and byte addition :4
int, byte and float addition :6.4
int, byte, float and double addition :8.800000095367432
float and double addition :4.800000095367432
float and float addition :4.8
double and double addition :4.8
float and double addition :4.800000095367432
```